# How do I add a library in php

Tags: php, windows, server, backend

I have windows and I'm writing program to Find PI to the Nth Digit, and when i use any function from the library of BC Math, i get the error of  "Fatal error: Call to undefined function", and When I entered on the main page of PHP and tried to add that library i get that, "The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension. You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use these functions"

I have tried to add the library but i couldn't

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful to know where your PHP install came from?

Comment: You must provide FULL exact error message, not just a stub

Comment: Is there any php_bcmath. dll in php extensions directory? if not, download and put it there and then enable it from php.ini